# Is this possible using Amazon AWS Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am considering using the AWS to power a web or kiosk based .NET application. The following is ultimately what I want to do:

- create a web based or kiosk type application that will allow users to browse for books/MP3s sold through Amazon
- add the items to a cart and, ultimately,
- checkout and charge a specific account.

I have seen that the affiliate program allows for affiliates to earn a percentage of each sale but it seems that the sale is done directly through Amazon after the user clicks a product link and is redirected to `amazon.com`. In my scenario the user cannot leave my application and the entire sale and potential download of an MP3 must be handled by my application.

Is this possible with the AWS API or am I misunderstanding the capabilities of the services? Any input and or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Amazon AWS as the scaffolding of your application. It can compute, store, deliver, and process data within your application. It also has a [payments component](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/fps/) which will [provide you what you are looking for](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=devfps/marketplace). The example linked to actually speaks to a *New Artist MP3 Discovery* application.

There is also an area that [depending on what you need a particular walk through is provided](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSGettingStartedGuide/NewProductDevelopment.html).

Comment: Thank you for the information that should point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is Cloud Service not 'web services' with output SOAP or REST

Answer (score 0):

AWS webservices just ease your infrastructure related activities. When using AWS you can just create a blank Ec2 instance and deploy your codes onto it.

Comment: The question was really about conducting sales via the Amazon website without redirecting to the website. Please provide more details about whether it is possible and how they might accomplish this if it is.